# Firebase Python 'Reference' object has no attribute 'limit_to_last'

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

```
import firebase_admin
enter code here`from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://databaseName.firebaseio.com'
})
ref = db.reference('dinosaurs')
snapshot = ref.order_by_child('height').limit_to_last(2).get()
for key in snapshot:
    print (key)
```

I've followed the instructions on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries) to the dot, but I am getting this error:

```
'Reference' object has no attribute 'limit_to_last'
```

I've made sure to install Python Admin SDK properly. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out!

Instead of using `order_by_child()`, I need to call `order_by_key()` EVEN IF I am not actually ordering by any key. Then I am able to call `limit_to_last()` or `limit_to_first()`.

Thanks guys!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `order_by_child()` returns a `Query` instance which has the `limit_to_last()` method on it. Here's an [integration test](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/master/integration/test_db.py#L247) from the Admin SDK repo, which demonstrates this use case. Your error message says `Reference object has no attribute`, which to me looks like you tried to call `limit_to_last()` on a reference.

Comment: What do you suggest Hiranya?